# Redux, useSelector and multiple slice in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a problem with useSelector in react.

This is my store at the moment:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { user: userSlice.reducer, auth: authSlice.reducer }
});
```

In my component I need to take only user state, but with useSelector I have some problem to choose correct Type. This is the useSelector:

```
useSelector<?????, User>((state) => state????)
```

Work in Javascript is very simple, but... Which type I need to use instead of ???? in my useSelector?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have typed correctly your slices, you can apply following types:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer
  }
});


type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch : () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector : TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```